# How can i reuse a complex type to define a sequence of itself (XML schema)

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

i'm new to xml schema. I have to convert manually a dtd file. These are two of the lines

```
<!ENTITY % field "a|b|c">
<!ELEMENT article (%field;)*>
```

I'd like to define the complextype which is equivalent to (a|b|c) and also the one equivalent to (a|b|c)* without rewriting the code.
The way i define (a|b|c) is

```
<xs:complexType name="abc">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="a"/>
        <xs:element ref="b"/>
        <xs:element ref="c"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

I don't know however how to define (a|b|c)* using the previous definition and without adding a subelement like i do below

```
<xs:element name="article">
<xs:complexType name="abc*">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="abcelement" type="abc" minOccur="0" maxOccur="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="article>
 <xs:complexType name="abc*">
        <xs:choice minOccur="0" maxOccur="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="a"/>
            <xs:element ref="b"/>
            <xs:element ref="c"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Define abc as a named xs:group which is a choice of a|b|c, then you can refer to this named group (a) directly within a complex type, and (b) within another complex type that allows repetition

```
<xs:group name="abc">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="a"/>
        <xs:element ref="b"/>
        <xs:element ref="c"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:group>

<xs:complexType name="abc">
  <xs:group ref="abc"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="abc-repeated">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:group ref="abc" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Not tested - there may be typos.